# What happens when I recieve the same game as a gift twice?

Tags: steam

A friend of mine has 2 spare copies of portal 2, and I which to give one to another friend and keep one for myself. When I receive the second copy, does it get added into my inventory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are given a game as a gift on Steam, it will land in your inventory, but you won't be able to play it right away. To play it, you need to add it to your *library*. This allows you to re-gift a game, in case you've received one you don't want and would like to trade it for some other game.

Although I have never received two or more copies of the same game as a gift, I believe that you can receive as many copies of one game, but can only add one of them to your library. In fact, if you buy a bundle which contains a game you already own, a copy of that game will land in your inventory as a gift. There is no reason to believe you *can't* hold multiple copies of the same game in your inventory.

Comment: The second part regarding gifting parts of a bundle is not necessarily true.  Humble Bundle type bundles, which gives you multiple games via one key, cannot have the separate games gifted.  It is stated in the bundle description when you purchase.  I haven't seen Steam bundles that behave like this yet, but it can.

Comment: "*There is no reason to believe you can't hold multiple copies of the same game in your inventory.*"; When you buy a multi-pack of a game, the extra copies will go to your inventory. When I bought a 4-pack of Magicite, for instance, I got 3 copies of the game in my inventory.